# How to draw how much of a fraction goes into another fraction

Tags: fractions

I have three questions.  All I want to draw a picture to show each of these:

a)Determine how many $\frac{1}{8}$’s are in $\frac{1}{4}$.

b)Determine how many $\frac{1}{3}$’s are in $\frac{1}{2}$.

c)Determine how many $\frac{1}{5}$’s are in $\frac{1}{20}$.

The first question is quite easy,  if we make a fraction bar, split it into fourths and shade in one box we get a fourth.  To see how many eighths we have, we divide each box in half to half 8 total pieces and we see we have 2 pieces since each box has two pieces and only one of our boxes is shaded.

The other two I am not sure.  Obviously we can compute an answer so I know for each $\frac{1}{2}$*$\frac{2}{3}$=$\frac{1}{3}$ and $\frac{1}{20}$*$\frac{4}{1}$=$\frac{1}{5}$.  How would I draw these out though.  I am having trouble drawing them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: pie chart]

Draw it however you want so long as you get across the meaning.  Here the darker (*and exploded*) pieces make up the intended $\frac{1}{2}$.  The chart is split into thirds.  You see that one full third as well as an additional half of a third are needed to add up to the half of the circle.

Your frustration and confusion likely stems from the fact that we needed to split up one of our segments into yet even smaller segments in order to make this work, in this case using segments of size $\frac{1}{6}$.

We see that we needed $1+\frac{1}{2}$, i.e. $\frac{3}{2}$ pieces of size $\frac{1}{3}$ to cover the region of size $\frac{1}{2}$.

---

The next part too, we can use pieces of smaller size to make it work out.

[image: pie chart 2]

Here, again, we have the darker exploded region referring to the target size, this time of size $\frac{1}{20}$.  We also pictured several regions of size $\frac{1}{5}$, equivalently written as size $\frac{4}{20}$.

We can see that only a quarter of the top right green region of size $\frac{1}{5}$ was used for the region of size $\frac{1}{20}$, so that is our answer.

In the end, the decisions on how to draw this all is very subjective.  Do it however it makes sense for you.  There is more than one way you could do this.  I merely happened to share how I would personally have done it.